# Change from (+) symbol to (-) after click (function(){

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I unable to change from (+) symbol to (-) symbol for after click function.

I have created a fiddle this is my issue: https://fiddle.jshell.net/yxdhxxj5/5/

I have created jquery file but i couldn't catch the solution.

Comment: where is your javascript in the jsfiddle? what are the errors? what have you tried?

Comment: you have to add javascript in your code

Answer (score 0):

See the following updated fiddle: 
https://fiddle.jshell.net/85s7b7jn/1/

The key is to create a class (I called it `.plus`) for `p.sidebarheading` that alters the content of its `:after` pseudo element to `+`. Then when anyone clicks on the parent sidebar, that class is toggled on or off, using boilerplate jQuery. (I added a jQuery dependency to your JS because you ought to be using it, as a minimum, for this sort of stuff. It makes your life much easier.)

Answer (score 0):

Change the JS and CSS code as below based on your fiddle https://fiddle.jshell.net/yxdhxxj5/5/

**JS:**

```
     $('.sidebarheading').on('click', function () {

         $('.subsidebar').toggle().addClass('.sidebarheading:after');
                     $(this).toggleClass('plus');

     });
```

**CSS:**

```
.plus.sidebarheading:after{
  content: '+';
}
```